# Unable To Share Text On Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, share

Hello Everyone I want to share the Text on Xamarin Form using Library plugin.share. I have successfully implemented the library and on android i can able to share the text but in iOS it returns me nothing. i have done the share code on button click event so when i click on button in iOS its doesn't returns me anything.i tried the Below code but doesn't got succeed

```
 CrossShare.Current.Share("Hii alll", "Share");
```

please help me to get out of this,thanks in advance

Comment: The question is not clear. What/Where are you sharing? What is `CrossShare`?

Comment: i want to share the text in what's app and email like Intent in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to take a look at `UIActivityViewController`, you can find the documentation here https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIActivityViewController/

And Xamarin.Forms specific example http://devcenter.wintellect.com/jwood/implementing-sharing-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: i have tried this example but not get succeed.can you share any full example related this if possible

Comment: by using the Plugin.share Nuget Package i can able to share on the android but not in iOS do you have any thing related to that

Comment: ok sir,it's my mistake i have implemented the link that you gave me and it's working perfectly i have edited that to share the string

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but I was having a similar issue and was able to resolve it.

First of all, you need to add the plugin `Plugin.Share` to ALL Xamarin.Forms projects (Portable, iOS, Android, UWP).

In the class that references the share code, add...

```
using Plugin.Share;
using Plugin.Share.Abstractions;
```

`CrossShare.Share()` doesn't work with strings, directly.  You need to new up a `ShareMessage`.

```
var title = "Title For The Share";
var message = "Text to share.";
await CrossShare.Current.Share(new ShareMessage { Text = message, Title = title });
```

I can't say specifically to iOS, as I don't have a Mac and can't test that project, but Android and Windows 10 is working.